How to pass a ZFS disk to qemu running on Windows 11 with FreeBSD 14 as guest os
I've virtualized the img file (created by dd'ing a real FreeBSD 14.0 installation) on Windows 11 wth qemu-kvm for Windows using the Hyper-V hypervisor. The parameters that I've used are the following ones :
I:\OS\qemu\FreeBSD\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64w.exe -accel whpx -machine q35 \
-cpu kvm64,hv_relaxed,hv_time,hv_synic -m 8G \
-device vmware-svga,id=video0,vgamem_mb=16,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1 \
-audiodev dsound,id=snd0 -device ich9-intel-hda \ 
-device hda-duplex,audiodev=snd0 \ 
-hda "I:\OS\qemu\FreeBSD\FreeBSD-ada1p2-qemu.img" -rtc base=localtime \
-device nec-usb-xhci,id=usb -device usb-tablet -device usb-kbd \
-smbios type=2 -nodefaults -netdev user,id=net0 \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:11:22:33 \ 
-device ich9-ahci,id=sata \ 
-bios "I:\OS\qemu\FreeBSD\OSX-KVM-master\OVMF_combined.fd"

It works good. Now,what I want to do is to pass the disk 8 to qemu,so that I can use it within the FreeBSD system. Disk 8 has ar ZFS file system. Qemu for Windows does not use /dev and the disk 8 is not even mapped as a drive in Windows,so what can I do ?
PS : I prefer to don't use virt-manager.

Windows raw disk device path is \.\PhysicalDrive[x], where x is disk device number starting from 0.
You can check your disk device numbers with Disk Management MMC Snap-in or with diskpart using list disk command.
In your case you should use following command-line:
I:\OS\qemu\FreeBSD\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64w.exe -accel whpx -machine q35 \
-cpu kvm64,hv_relaxed,hv_time,hv_synic -m 8G \
-device vmware-svga,id=video0,vgamem_mb=16,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1 \
-audiodev dsound,id=snd0 -device ich9-intel-hda \ 
-device hda-duplex,audiodev=snd0 \ 
-hda "I:\OS\qemu\FreeBSD\FreeBSD-ada1p2-qemu.img" -rtc base=localtime \
-device nec-usb-xhci,id=usb -device usb-tablet -device usb-kbd \
-smbios type=2 -nodefaults -netdev user,id=net0 \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:11:22:33 \ 
-device ich9-ahci,id=sata \ 
-bios "I:\OS\qemu\FreeBSD\OSX-KVM-master\OVMF_combined.fd"
-drive file=\\.\PhysicalDrive8,format=raw,media=disk

Here's an example of QEMU raw device mapping from Arch Wiki
My silimar answer, I'm sure it's more helpful to have full text instead of simple link.
